# Golang import package remove by vscode

Tags: go, go-gorm

I start to work with go and i am happy :)
But i got a strange problem with package import.

I got a file dto.go :

```
package dto

import (
    "time"
)

type TaskResponse struct {
    ID          uint      `json:"id"`
    Title       string    `json:"title"`
    Description string    `json:"description"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

A simple response object, but a task have a Status param.

I got a file model.go :

```
package model

// Status struct
type Status struct {
    ID   uint
    Name string
}
```

The problem is that i would like to add in TaskResponse the Status object, but when i add this, i got a "undefined Status" and when i force the import of the package vscode remove it automaticly...

Someone know what is my problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I can see, you have imported only "time" package and not "model" that `Status` is in

Comment: Yes this is what i believe too, but when i import it, vscode remove it automaticly because he think that it is not used...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, just need to use model.Status in the object TaskResponse

Comment: Note that VSCode is probably using the [`goimports`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports) tool (or something similar). This tool automatically removes imports that are not used and automatically inserts imports that are missing. You should be able to confirm this by removing the `model` import but keeping the `model.Status` in object `TaskResponse` and then saving the file. Note also that the reason this exists is because in Go it is illegal to import packages without using them just as it is illegal to reference an unimported identifier, and this tool fixes those errors.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happening is because of what you imported, you didn't use it in the program, so Golang deletes unnecessary dependencies.